# MS SQL insert into two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have four tables.

```
Person(
GUID uniqueidentifier
LastName varchar(20)
FirstName varchar(20)
SSN varchar(20)
ResidenceAddressGUID uniqueidentifier
)

Adress(
GUID uniqueidentifier
Street varchar(50)
Zip varchar(10)

)
Code(
CodeNumber
PersonGUID
Street
Zip

)
Tmp(
FirstName
LastName
Street
Zip
CodeNumber
)
```

And I want to move the data from Tmp to Person and Adress.  What is the simplest way to do it?

EDIT:

I actually found out that TMP has a field "Code" that should be copied to the Code table with the street-adress and zip, no relationship to the address table.

Comment: Should ResidenceAddressGUID refer to Address table for new records?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that ResidenceAddressGUID should refer to the inserted corresponding address record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (Address&Zip) combination is unique, you could use this:

```
INSERT INTO Address
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.Street,
    T.Zip
FROM 
    TMP T LEFT JOIN
    Address A ON A.Zip = T.Zip AND Z.Street = T.Street
WHERE
    A.GUID IS NULL

INSERT INTO Person (
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    ResidenceAddressGUID) 
SELECT
    T.FirstName,
    T.LastName,
    A.GUID 
FROM 
    TMP T INNER JOIN
    Address A ON A.Street = T.Street AND A.ZIP = T.ZIP
```

If they are not unique, you should have a look at mssql INSERT OUTPUT option

Comment: Thanks. Address and zip should be unique, but can never say for sure. There might be to persons that share the same address though. How would it look with insert output instead?

Comment: I've updated answer by adding DISTINCT to Address statement - so there will be one address record and two person records referring the same address

Comment: Made another edit to ensure that existing address will not be loaded again if it was loaded somewhen before. No need to use INSERT OUTPUT in this case.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a nice solution. I've added some complexity to the description. How would you manage that?

Comment: It should be exactly the same approach as for Address table. Also, if there can be some old addresses without code and now you have this code for those addresses from TMP - then you will need an additional UPDATE FROM statement.

Comment: Thanks. Actually Code-table has a relationship with Person-table through PersonGUID in Code.

Comment: The query works somewhat. The only problem is that I get 717 new Persons and there is only 694 in the tmp-table

Comment: Could it be that two Persons can have the same address?

Comment: No, it should not. "INSERT INTO Address" ignores duplicates and ensures that new duplicates does not appear. This could happen if Address table already had duplicated addresses that appear in new persons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `INSERT INTO` statement combined with a `SELECT` statement to map the columns from TMP you want to insert into ADDRESS.

```
INSERT INTO Address(Street, Zip)
SELECT
    Street,
    Zip
FROM TMP
```

Also, you do the same thing for PERSON table.

```
INSERT INTO Person(LastName, FirstName, ResidenceAddressGUID)
SELECT
    T.Street,
    T.Zip,
    A.GUID
FROM TMP T INNER JOIN ADDRESS A 
               ON T.Street = A.Street
                   AND T.Zip = A.Zip
```

Based on your later comments, I modified my queries and I hope now you understand the pattern and can do the queries for the `CODE` table yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to connect the adress GUID to the Person in ResidenceAdressGUID

Comment: @isshin I've updated my answer based on your comments

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually forgot that every person also has an SSN. In this solution you add Person first. and then you add Address record. But wont the ResidenceAdressGUID in Person be NULL since you have not added the address yet?

Comment: @isshin Well, which of the two columns is set to auto complete? The `ResidenceAddressGUID` in Person or `GUID` in Address? Or none?

Comment: the Guid in Address is autocreated on insert

Comment: @isshin Then, indeed. You should insert records in Address first and then in Person, using the GUID from Address in ResidenceAddressGUID. I'll modify my queries.

Comment: @isshin I have modified my queries to insert data into Person and Address. I assume you understnad now how the pattern works and can do it yourself for the `CODE` table.

Comment: Thanks! I'm experiencing a small bug though. I have 694 Persons in the tmp table. But when running the queries I get 717. Might have something to do with that some of the Persons have the same address. Any easy way around it?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't insert into multiple tables in one MySQL command. You can however use transactions.

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PERSON(LastName, FirstName)
SELECT
FirstName,
LastName
FROM TMP
INSERT INTO ADDRESS(Street)
SELECT
Street
FROM TMP;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I think the question is about `MS SQL`, not about `MySQL`, please check question again.

Comment: @realspirituals: MS SQL is quite prominent in the title of the question

Answer (score 0):

`Select` statements can be used in combination with an insert statement to copy data from one table to another.  One caveat, you must include a primary key for the tmp data your moving. In my example, I have included a sequence, which would work with an Oracle database.  Depending on how the keys are assigned you may be able to omit the sequence, such as when a MySql autonumber exists.

```
insert into Person(GUID, FirstName, LastName) 
select PERSON_SEQ.nextval, FirstName, LastName from Tmp;

insert into Adress(GUID, Street, Zip) 
select ADRESS_SEQ.nextval, Street,Zip from Tmp;
```